# Problemas com input_shape usando keras

Tags: python-3.x, inteligência-artificial, redes-neurais, keras

Olá,

estou tentando fazer meu primeiro codigo de ANN para prever o preço de casas. Separei os datasets em treino e teste, no entanto, estou encontrando alguns problemas na hora de compilar meu código abaixo:

```
    x_train =  train[col]
    y_train = train['price']
    x_test = test[col]
    y_test = test['price']  
    model = Sequential([
        Dense(32, activation='relu', input_dim=(11,)), 
        Dense(32, activation='relu'), 
        Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')
    ])
    model.compile(
        optimizer='sgd',
        loss='binary_crossentropy',
        metrics= ['accuracy']
    )
    hist = model.fit(
        x_train,
        x_train,
        batch_size=32, 
        epochs=100,
        validation_data=(x_test, y_test)
    )
```

Que retorna o segundo erro:

```
 ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_31 to have shape (1,) but got array with shape (11,)
```

[image: Imagem do dataset]

Comment: Porque x_train e repetido em model.fit()?

Answer (score 0):

O problema está em `model.fit`, pois espera-se que a variável target tenha o mesmo formato que definido no `Sequential()`.

Então, quando faz

```
hist = model.fit(
        x_train,
        x_train,
        batch_size=32, 
        epochs=100,
        validation_data=(x_test, y_test)
    )
```

você coloca `x_train` como target, gerando o erro.

O correto seria

```
hist = model.fit(
        x_train,
        y_train,
        batch_size=32, 
        epochs=100,
        validation_data=(x_test, y_test)
    )
```